# JQuery string match

Tags: jquery, match

I want to match certain attribute. Why doesnt it match data-super-11 in this code? And how do I make sure it works? I will always have this form: data-super-'followed by third' word.

```
var d = '<div data-super-high="a" data-super="b" data-super-11="c" />';

$.each($(d).data(), function (i, e) { 

    if(/super/.test(i)){    
        console.log('name='+ i + ' value=' +e);
    }
});
```

Comment: jQuery doesn't match strings ?

Comment: Also, `data-super-11` is not valid, so it's never found !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that attribute `data-super-11` is not recognized as *data* attribute since due to the number character after the dash `-` it doesn't meet name requirements.

From [`The algorithm for getting the list of name-value pairs`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes) (of data attributes):

> 3. For each name in list, for each U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS character (-) in the name that is followed by a lowercase ASCII letter, remove the U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS character (-) and replace the character that followed it by the same character converted to ASCII uppercase.

However `data-super-11` is still normal attribute (not *data* though) so you can for example read it using `attributes` collection:

```js
var d = '<div data-super-high="a" data-super="b" data-super-11="c" />';

$.each($(d)[0].attributes, function (i, e) { 
    if (/super/.test(e.name)) {
        document.body.innerHTML += 'name='+ e.name + ' value=' + e.value + '<br>';
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

<sub>Note, to match only data attributes add the check `e.name.indexOf('data-') == 0`.</sub>

**UPD**. Thanks to adeneo in comments, who found out that using dataset API it's possible to read data attributes with numbers after the hyphen.

Comment: That is correct, it's what the spec says, a number shouldn't follow a hyphen, as it's invalid, but spending the last 15 minutes fiddling around, it actually works in native JS ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z26qann0/)), it's the way jQuery internally handles the conversion calling `jQuery.camelCase(name.slice(5))` on the attribute, and then doing `key.replace(/([A-Z])/g, "-$1").toLowerCase()`, that looses the data attribute, as `1` can't be converted to upperCase and doesn't match the regex.